# Jasmine Testing Issues with mockup

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I have a jasmine coffeescript test like the one below. I'm trying to mock an li.active event and test that in the javascript. Below is the test spec.

```
describe 'Interviews', ->
  describe 'TTI.questionAdd', ->
    it 'should close modal when choose a question is empty', ->
     spyOn(TTI.Position, 'questionCancel')

     htmlMock = '<form action="javascript:void();>"'
     htmlMock += '<ul id="#question-create-methods">'
     htmlMock += '<li class="active"><a href="#">Choose a Question</a></li>'
     htmlMock += '</ul>'
     htmlMock += '<input class="btn-question-add" type="submit">'
     htmlMock += '</form>'

     $(htmlMock).appendTo('body')

     $('.btn-question-add').on('click', TTI.Position.questionAdd)


     console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML)

     $(".btn-question-add").trigger('click')
     ...
```

And here is my real coffeescript file snippet

```
TTI.Position.questionAdd = (e) ->
 e.preventDefault()
 t = $(this)
 id = t.attr 'id'
 tab = $('.nav-tab.active').data('type')
 type = 'vod'
 duration = parseInt($('.js-duration-mins').val()) * 60 + parseInt($('.js-duration-secs').val())
 switch $('#question-create-methods').find('li.active a').html()
  when 'Choose a Question'
   body = $('#library_questions').find('a.active').html()
  when 'Write a Question'
   body = $('#question_write_body').val()
  when 'Custom Question Bank'
   question_bank_id = $('#question-custom').find('a.active').data('id')
   body = $('#question-custom').find('a.active').html()
   ...
```

But when I print out $('#question-create-methods').find('li.active a').html() to the console from the actual javascript, it's always undefined!! This is making me nuts as it's preventing me to test this properly by mocking the 'li.active a' element. What am I doing wrong? It could be that the javascript is getting executed before the dom is loaded, so how do I make sure that is not the case.

Comment: Just fixed the formatting. Do you see why the mockup is failing?

Comment: Not sure but why is your `$('.btn-question-add').on` before the `appendTo('body')`?

Comment: Good point, fixed that. But the problem still remains.

Comment: `"#question-create-methods"` and `"question-create-methods"` are very different things. The first is a selector that looks for `id="question-create-methods"`, the second is the value of `id` that the selector is looking for. `id="#question-create-methods"` is almost never what you want in your HTML. Sorry, I probably should have spotted that right away.

Comment: also, why all the += after all coffeescript has multiline strings

Comment: Thanks guys! Fixed now.